# Saving objects with FindObjectsOfTypeAll()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a save-Method to save informations about every block with one of five specific tags, like position, health, rotation etc.

I first want to get all objects (even inactive ones), so i use the FindObjectsOfTypeAll()-Method.

Then i go with a foreach loop through all of the objects that have been found, and check if they have the right tag and if they do, i save them.

This is the code i use:

```
GameObject[] allObjects = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof (GameObject)) as GameObject[];

using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(dir + "blocksSave.dat"))
{
    Debug.Log(allObjects.Length);
    foreach (GameObject block in allObjects)
    {
        bool isActive = block.activeSelf;
        block.SetActive(true);
        if (block.tag == "WoodBlock" || block.tag == "WoodSteps" || block.tag == "WoodRamp" || block.tag == "GlasBlock" || block.tag == "WoodDoor")
        {                    
            // SAVE
            write.WriteLine(block.tag + "," + block.transform.position.x + "," + block.transform.position.y + "," + block.transform.position.z + "," + block.GetComponent<BlockControl>().GetHealth().x + "," + block.GetComponent<BlockControl>().GetHealth().y + "," + block.transform.rotation.x + "," + block.transform.rotation.y + "," + block.transform.rotation.z);
        }

        block.SetActive(isActive);
    }
write.Close();
}
```

I debugged this and the line `if (block.tag == "WoodBlock" || ...)` works fine.

The problem is the next line:

```
write.WriteLine(...);
```

here i get a `nullReferenceException`, where it tells me:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object

And i can't figure out why?!

Comment: Can you add a Debug line in your if and check which object is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is very probably that

```
block.GetComponent<BlockControl>()
```

returns `null` for one of your found `GameObjects` since it simply does not have that component.

---

Instead you could use

```
Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<BlockCo troll>();
```

to be sure you only have all the components of type `BlockControl` in a separate list.

---

Than you can use a List to easier filter the objects for the tag instead of those `||` conditions

```
var searchedTags = new List<string>()
{
    "WoodBlock",
    "WoodSteps",
    "WoodRamp",
    "GlasBlock",
    "WoodDoor"
};

if (searchedTags.Contains(block.gameObject.tag))
{
    ....
}
```

or even esier use Linq to only get the objects you are interested in:

```
var objectsOfInterest = allObjects.Where(obj => searchedTags.Contains(obj.gameObject.tag)).ToList();
```

---

I would also only use the `StreamWriter` for actually writing and do nothing else within that `using` block.

And note that if you are using a `StreamWriter` inside of a `using` block you don't have to use `write.Close()` since it is disposed automatically after the `using` block finishes.

---

So in complete I would use something like

```
var searchedTags = new List<string>()
{
    "WoodBlock",
    "WoodSteps",
    "WoodRamp",
    "GlasBlock",
    "WoodDoor"
};

// This list is used to get all GameObject
// keep track which where active and activate all
var allObjects = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<GameObject>();

// Here we get all BlockController components
var allBlockObjects = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<BlockController>();

// finally we only get BlockControllers with the tags we want
var objectsOfInterest = allBlockObjects.Where(obj => searchedTags.Contains(obj.gameObject.tag)).ToList();

Debug.Log("objects total: " + allObjects.Length);
Debug.Log("block objects: " + allBlockObjects.Length);
Debug.Log("objects of interest: " + objectsOfInterest.Length);

// Step 1 keep track which GameObjects where active and activate all

var objectWasNotActive = new List<GameObject>();

foreach (var obj in allObjects)
{
    if(!obj.activeSelf)
    {
        // keep track which objects where not active
        objectWasNotActive.Add(obj);
    }

    // Set all to true
    obj.SetActive(true);
}

// Step 2 save your BlockControllers with searched tags

using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(dir + "blocksSave.dat"))
{
    foreach (var block in objectsOfInterest)
    {  
        // Here you already have components of type BlockController
        // so you don't need to get them 

        // But GetHealth might also return null so maybe you want to check that too
        // It is up to you whether you want to skip or fill it with default values in such case
        var health = block.GetHealth();
        if(health == null)
        {
            //option 1 skip
            continue;

            // OR option 2 default e.g.
            // Assuming it is Vector2
            health = Vector2.zero;
        }

        // SAVE
        write.WriteLine(
            block.gameObject.tag + "," 
            + block.transform.position.x + "," 
            + block.transform.position.y + "," 
            + block.transform.position.z + "," 
            + health.x + "," 
            + health.y + "," 
            + block.transform.rotation.x + "," 
            + block.transform.rotation.y + "," 
            + block.transform.rotation.z
        );        
    }
}

// Step 3 disable those GameObjects again that where not active before
foreach(var obj in objectWasNotActive)
{
    obj.SetActive(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it's really hard to debug this without seeing the code, but try checking this first.

- Check if `write` is being properly initialized without errors, sometimes it fails silently.
- Are you sure that all of your objects with those tags have the component `BlockControl` on them ?

try updating your code to this just to check where exactly is it failing

```
if (block.tag == "WoodBlock" || block.tag == "WoodSteps" || block.tag == "WoodRamp" || block.tag == "GlasBlock" || block.tag == "WoodDoor")
    {
        Debug.Log(block.name);
        Debug.Log(block.GetComponent<BlockControl>());
        Debug.Log(block.GetComponent<BlockControl>().GetHealth());
        // SAVE
        write.WriteLine(block.tag + "," + block.transform.position.x + "," + block.transform.position.y + "," + block.transform.position.z + "," + block.GetComponent<BlockControl>().GetHealth().x + "," + block.GetComponent<BlockControl>().GetHealth().y + "," + block.transform.rotation.x + "," + block.transform.rotation.y + "," + block.transform.rotation.z);
    }
```

This way you can find out which `block` is causing the issue and if the problem is with the component or the `GetHealth()` function.